# Can't choose to use Require.js when running karma init

Tags: npm, requirejs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-requirejs

I'm trying to create a configuration file to run karma tests including Jasmine and requirejs, so I run `karma init xyz.conf.js`, and the script asks me:

- `What testing framework to use?` I have only available jasmine, as expected
- `Do you want to use require.js?` When this question appears, it gets automatically answered `no` and moves on to the next question

I suppose it must have something to do with a missing dependency. I've installed, in this order:

```
npm install karma --save-dev (0.13.16)
npm install jasmine --save-dev (2.4.1)
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev (0.3.6)
npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev (0.2.2)
npm install requirejs --save-dev (2.1.22)
npm install karma-requirejs --save-dev (0.2.2)

npm -g install karma-cli --save-dev (0.1.2)
```

*NOTE: I've included the installed version number*

Do I have something missing or misconfigured? What do I have to do so that `karma init` allows me to specify that I want to use `Require.js`? Can I solve it by modifying the `.conf.js` by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the config process skipped the requirejs option, but you can manually add the `requirejs` framework to your karma config file. A config file I set up with requirejs has the following framework value:

`frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs']`

However, there is probably some more configuration you'll have to do in order to get it to run properly. The docs for Karma have a section for configuring the test environment to run with requirejs: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it working. However I had to manually change the .conf.js file, and take into account some other things which are not well documented in the link you provide in your answer, which I had already read.Unless someone has a better solution, I'll answer thequestion myself with some additional notes.

Comment: @JotaBe Any plans on replying with what you did?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and I think it is possibly a bug in the CLI on Windows.

When it is working you can select any framework (e.g. mocha, nunit, qunit, nodeunit) by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or using the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys) on the first question "Which testing framework do you want to use ?".

When it is not working you can only select `jasmine` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will skip the Require.js question.

I don't know the exact steps, but I was able to get into the working state by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> through a few options then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and running `karma init` again.

After repeating this a few times I got into the working state where I could select any framework and select Require.js.